# Bind "this" to TypeScript Lambda

Tags: javascript, typescript, this, function-binding

Say I have a lambda in TypeScript:

```
 myArray.forEach(o => o.x = this.x);
```

The value of `this` becomes `window` instead of the calling object. What I'd really like to do is:

```
 myArray.forEach(o => { o.x = this.x; }.bind(this));
```

But I don't see that as an option in TypeScript. How can I override `this` in a TypeScript lambda body?

Comment: Of course, you could always use `myArray.forEach(o => o.x = this, this.x)` :-)

Comment: Well that's actually the answer - make it official and I'll accept it. :) I didn't think to check for other parameters to `forEach`.

Comment: Yeah, but you asked about typescript lambdas in general; the additional parameter won't help you everywhere.

Comment: Yes it does .... `myArray.forEach(o => o.x = this.x, this)` ... is the solution.

Comment: @JoshM Can you give more code to reproduce your issue? I'm not understanding it... http://goo.gl/c2lqYZ

Comment: Inside the lambda, `this` defaults to `window` instead of the owner of the calling function. So, passing `this` as the second parameter to `Array.forEach` "fixes" this issue and the lambda's `this` reference will be the same as the calling function's `this`.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI even without a lambda the default `this` in a for each is `window` e.g. :

```
[1].forEach( function ( o ) { console.log( this ) }); // window
```

To fix the this with `bind` you need to use a `function` and not a lambda (which lexically scopes the meaning of `this`).

```
var foo = {};
[1].forEach( function ( o ) { console.log( this ) }.bind( foo ) ); // object `foo`
```

Alternatively you can use the second argument for `forEach` as mentioned by Bergi.

Comment: Actually, *with* a lambda (or correctly: arrow function) the `this` is *not* `window`.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic then : not _necessarily_ `window` unless the immediate upper scope is global && you are in a browser environment.

Comment: Your first two recommendations are not necessary. Your last recommendation is the correct answer: `myArray.forEach(o => o.x = this.x, this);`